# Is there going to be an Iron Man 4 after all prototypes are finally destroyed for good?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, marvel, iron-man-3

I'm new to the Marvel universe, having recently watched the Iron Man series, Captain America and the Avengers. I like the IM series so much that I want to know is there a 4th part going to come?

If so, how can Stark become Iron Man in any forthcoming movie as all his prototypes were destroyed in IM3?

For that matter, how can he even appear in Avengers or any other Marvel movie without an IM suit?

Comment: for sure not a new one in the next 5-6 years, it was not on the list marvel released 2 days ago listing all upcoming movies. however ironman will be in 3 more avengers movies, as well as the next captain america movie.

Comment: The fact that he destroyed his prototypes somehow bars him from creating a new one? He built the original in a cave... with a box of scraps. He had no plans or blueprints. I'd also suggest watching the trailer for *The Avengers: Age of Ultron* which shows new suits.

Comment: @phantom42 I asked this question in the office the other day - my approach was less "he's destroyed all of the suits" and more "he destroyed all the suits because he was going to lose Pepper otherwise", so what changes for the second Avengers film to allow him to build more suits?

Comment: I'm not making this an answer because I don't have a source, but I remember reading that, out-of-universe, RDJ (And Hemsworth and Evans) only signed a 5-movie contract: three solo films and 2 *Avengers* titles. So unless RDJ signs another contract (And unless Marvel offers; he's pretty expensive for them), it doesn't seem likely

Comment: @Moo There's some context there you're missing.  He was building the suits as a coping mechanism for some trauma he was dealing with.  Him destroying the suits represented progress in dealing with said trauma as well as addressing Pepper's concern.

Comment: right keen has it, the suits wernt the problem, it was he couldnt cope with the trauma, and ignored pepper, while building suits to try to occupy his mind.

Comment: Incidentally, I don't see what is "primarily opinion-based" about my question. There has to be a direct and to-the-point answer to "Is there going to be an Iron-man 4" ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

He can easily make further suits.  This is evidenced by the Iron Man suits we see in the *Avengers: Age of Ultron* trailers.

As to whether there will be an *Iron Man 4*, we don't know.  When asked on the subject a few days ago Kevin Feige was [cagey](http://www.movieweb.com/marvel-phase-3-movies-interview-kevin-feige):

> If there are more years after 2019, then there will be more possibilities. I hope there are more years.

At the event that quote is from, Marvel announced their Phase 3 plans, which go out to 2019.  So if there's going to be an *Iron Man 4*, it'll be after 2019, which is why Feige references that year in the quote above.

It's also worth noting that it's been announced that Tony Stark will play a big role in *Captain America: Civil War*, the next Captain America film.  So, we'll likely see Iron Man in action there too.

Comment: That's a great quote, but kind of ominous...  What does Feige know about the end of the world, that we don't...?

Comment: @Nerrolken Well, *Thor: Ragnarok* is out in 2017, so Feige should have some idea of how the world ends by now...

Comment: So 2020? DC has both Green Lantern *and* Cyborg movies coming out that year. Good luck competing with those, Marvel!

Answer (score 7):

**Unknown, but certainly not any time soon.**

At an event earlier this week, Marvel announced their Phase Three lineup which *doesn't* include a fourth Iron Man film. This means the earliest we could have *Iron Man 4* would be 2019 (when the last Phase Three film is due to be released).

After the announcement, Kevin Feige was asked about the prospect of another Iron Man film. MovieWeb has [some quotes from the interview](http://www.movieweb.com/marvel-phase-3-movies-interview-kevin-feige), and he gave a somewhat cryptic answer:

> If there are more years after 2019, then there will be more possibilities. I hope there are more years.

So perhaps they want to make another Iron Man film, but there isn't room for it for now, and a lot could change in the next five years.

Note, however, that this doesn't mean he won't be in future MCU films. For example, the trailer for *Avengers: Age of Ultron*

> shows a new, traditional-style, suit, and an entirely new Hulkbuster suit. These must have been built since the end of *Iron Man 3*, so presumably blowing the old ones up didn't dampen his desire to continue building.

Comment: "the event" Okay but this would be a better answer if you told us _what_ "event".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: the event was Marvel's press conference to announce their Phase Three lineup

Comment: “This means the earliest we could have Iron Man 4 would be 2019” — I’m pretty sure if RDJ decided he was up for an *Iron Man 4*, they’d move some stuff around. The last *Iron Man* took in $1.2 billion at the box office. That’s more than *The Dark Knight*.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite True, but I doubt they failed to ask him.  If they're saying no Iron Man until 2019, it's undoubtedly because they tried to make it work within that timeframe and couldn't.  Thus, the earliest would be 2019.

Comment: @Nerrolken: fair point, could be.

Comment: @alexwlchan: Yes, _I_ know that, but it should be part of the answer. Instead of just saying "the event". Do you disagree? If so, why?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Read the rest of the sentence?  It says what the event contained right there.

Comment: @Keen: I don't know how to make this any easier for you to understand. Stack Exchange answers are not news bulletins that rely on knowledge of current affairs. To say "the event" the answer would have to tell us _which event_, _where_ and _when_ to be a good answer in that regard. Fortunately Paul got it and has improved the post using a rather ingenious approach that involves only a single changed word, by bypassing identification of the specific event entirely and concentrating the paragraph on its purpose and outcome.

Comment: Guys, guys, stop applauding, please. Actually no, continue.